# Installing the SpatialHadoop framework op top of Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2

Does anyone has knowledge or installed the SpatialHadoop? The SpatialHadoop is an open source framework embedded to the Hadoop system to support the spatial computation. Indeed, I have installed it following this Hadoop installation tutorial [here](http://letsdobigdata.wordpress.com/2014/01/13/setting-up-hadoop-1-2-1-multi-node-cluster-on-amazon-ec2-part-2/) . After the step 1.4 of this tutorial, I downloaded the spatialHadoop, so,  when I start the Hadoop, the SpatialHadoop library will be uploaded.

However, as I tried to execute the example commands of the spatialHadoop [here](https://github.com/aseldawy/spatialhadoop2) ,

- the first command is executed without errors but there is no reduce phase
- the second command did not run because of the error java.lang.NullPointerException

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

### First command - 'generate',

The function which it calls, will depend on the input parameter 'size'. If size is greater that (100*1024*1024), then for reduce phase it will check whether the objects are in one partition or not.
If all the objects are in one partition, there is no need for a reduce phase. But if there are more than one partition, then reduce phase is required to group shapes of the same partition together.

### Second command - 'index'

Null pointer Exception is due to input parameter - 'shape:'. 
In index command, along with input, output, and sindex, shape parameter is also required.